# How to check if a file still exists using a file descriptor

Tags: c, unix, freebsd, file-descriptor

I have a file descriptor that is set to a positive value with the result of a open() function so this fd is indicating a file. When i delete the actual file fd is still a positive integer. I want to know that if i delete a file for some reason, how can i know that this file descriptor is not valid anymore. In short, how can i know that the file that fd is indicating, still there or not. I am trying to do this in C on FreeBSD.

Comment: Try writing or reading to the file. That should return an error.

Comment: @RedX that's not how UNIX works.

Comment: Yes i know that i have to read or open that file but is there a way to open or read a file with just fd? is there an io function for reading or opening with just fd, no path or FILE*

Comment: @HasanBozok - you can't `open` a file with an fd - open _returns_ a fd. It's only an int.

Comment: What behavior do you want if you get a file descriptor on `/p/a/t/h`, and then unlink `/p/a/t/h`, but `/p/a/t/h/2` is a link to the same file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix systems let you delete open files (or rather, delete all references to the file from the filesystem). But the file descriptor is *still valid*. Any read and write calls will be successful, as they would with the filename still there.

In other words, you cannot fully delete a file until the file descriptor is closed. Once closed, the file will then be removed automatically.

With a valid file descriptor, you can check if the filename still exists, e.g.

```
printf("%d\n", buf.st_nlink);  // 0 means no filenames
```

Where `buf` is a `struct stat` initialised with `fstat`.

Comment: Thanks for advice but this is a different situation i am facing. I just need to check if the file that fd indicates still there or not. If not what is the way to learn that via fd?

Comment: @HasanBozok - You can use `fstat` on the valid file descriptor to get the number of hard links. If it's 0, the filename(s) has been deleted.

Comment: @teppic, Is there any way [`ioctl`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/ioctl.html) can be used to actually cause the file to be deleted? If that were possible, would that be dangerous?

Comment: @AnishRam - the kernel controls this - and the only way a file is deleted is if there are no existing hard links, and no open file descriptors on the inode.

Comment: @AnishRam No. If you want the file to be deleted, close() the descriptor. (all descriptors referring to that file needs to be closed before the kernel will delete it.)

Answer (score 1):

Before writing to the file you could check if it is still there using `access()`

```
if (access("/yourfile",W_OK)!=-1) {
    //Write on the file
}
```

You can also do fstat on the descriptor:

```
struct stat statbuf;
fstat(fd,&statbuf);
if (statbuf.st_nlink > 0) {
    //File still exists
}
```

But it will slow your software down a lot, and also some program could link the file somewhere else and unlink the original name, so that the file would still be existing but under a different name/location, and this method would not detect that.

A much better alternative would be to use `inotify` on GNU/Linux, or kqueue on bsd, but I've never used the 2nd one.

You can use these API to watch changes in directories and get notifications from the kernel and get an event when your file is being deleted by some other process, and do something about it.

Keep in mind that this events are not in real time, so you could still use the file for a couple of milliseconds before getting the event.